# How to match more than 2 number in a row?

Tags: python, list, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 data frames that I would like to match more than 2 numbers that match in the row I'm looking up.

```
import pandas as pd 

cols = ['Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6']
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2,4,6,8,9,10]], columns=cols)

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,2,4,5,6,8],
               [2,5,6,20,22,23,34],
               [3,8,12,13,34,45,46],
               [4,9,10,14,29,32,33],
               [5,1,22,13,23,33,35],
               [6,1,6,7,8,9,10],
               [7,0,2,3,5,6,8]], 
               columns = ['Id','Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

I have this code that matches but i would like to enhance by matching more than 2 numbers
in the row.

```
 # convert the values in the first dataframe to a list
   vals_to_find = df1.iloc[0].tolist()

 # Print the values to find
   print("Vals to find:", vals_to_find)

 # Create an empty list to hold the matching IDs
   matching_ids = []

# iterate through the big dataframe 
  for index, row in df2.iterrows():

  rowlist = row.tolist()       # convert the row to a list

# keep the id for later, and extract the other values for evaluation
  id = rowlist[0]
  vals = rowlist[1:]

# count the number of values in one list against another list
counter = sum(elem in vals_to_find for elem in vals)

# If the number of matches is greater than 2, then grab the ID
if counter > 2:
    matching_ids.append({'ID': id})

# Print the matching IDs 
  print('Matching IDS:', matching_ids)
```

I would like my results to be something like that..

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([[6,1,6,7,8,9,10]],             
           columns = ['Id', 'Num1','Num2','Num3','Num4','Num5','Num6'])
```

Why 6. Because Id 6 has 8,9,10 that has more than 2 numbers match side by side.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood your question right. You can construct a mask (using `set.intersection`) and then using the mask on `df2`:

```py
vals_to_find = set(df1.iloc[0])
mask = df2.loc[:, "Num1":].apply(
    lambda x: len(vals_to_find.intersection(x)) > 2, axis=1
)
print(df2[mask])
```

Prints:

```
   Id  Num1  Num2  Num3  Num4  Num5  Num6
0   1     1     2     4     5     6     8
5   6     1     6     7     8     9    10
6   7     0     2     3     5     6     8
```

Comment: No not quite. i updated my question. hopefully it explains more.

Comment: @Chris I don't understand. With your new input, why only `6` should be in the result? Why not index `1` and `7`. Index `7` has values 2, 6, 8 wich are common with `vals_to_find`

Comment: 6 should be the answer because more than 2 numbers match side by side. 1 and 7 does match but not more than 2 numbers match side by side.